# Shutdown/restart command using a variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, shutdown, reboot

I am working on a GUI reboot modul in a tool of mine.
I want to use the command prompt "shutdown" command line for this.
Its purpose is to replace the "shutdown -i" on multiple servers and then I can ping them automatically to check if the reboot was succesfull.

In CMD the command line looks like this:

```
shutdown /r /t 30 /m \\server /c "reboot reason"
```

In my script I will ask for the:

- reason = $comment
- time = $time (the value and also in a checkbox if it is required or not)
- server name = $server

I will test with a few "if"s the time option, is it checked or not and that the reboot reason is not empty and then add all of them to a variable:

```
$reboot = "/r /t " + $time + "/m \\" + $server + "/c " + $comment
```

and then use the variable in the command in powershell:

```
& shutdown $reboot
```

My question is will this work? Did anyone use it like this? Or there is a better way to do it?
I can't test it for a few days because I don't have any servers right now on the network that I can reboot feely.

Comment: I think what you have should work but you could also use the `Stop-Computer` cmdlet which is there for the same reason . Although you cant seem to get comments with that

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I looked into that restart-computer command, and it looks pretty "variable frindly" but cand't find the "comment" option (it is a must have field for me)

This is the Syntax i'v found:
      Stop-Computer [[-ComputerName] string[]] [[-Credential] PSCredential] [-Authentication AuthenticationLevel] [-Impersonation ImpersonationLevel] [-AsJob] [-Force] [-ThrottleLimit int] [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [CommonParameters]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, yes. I would also recommend using an array for the parameters to keep it clean.

```
$time = 120
$server = "mycomputer"
$comment = "this is my comment."
$reboot = @("/r", "/t", $time, "/m", "\\$server", "/c", $comment)

& shutdown $reboot
```

Or you could try doing it using WMI (untested):

```
$time = 120
$comment = "this is my comment."
$server = "mycomputer"

Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName $server -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Name Win32ShutdownTracker -ArgumentList @($time, $comment, 0, 2)
```